# Media queries width issue

Tags: css, media-queries

Maybe this a newbie question but I'm a little bit confused about media queries.

I have a nexus 5 which is 1920x1080 and I'm trying to change the background of the body depending of the width.

This is the code

```
body {
    background: black;
}

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
body {
    background: red;
}
}

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: 992px) {
body{
    background: yellow;
}
}

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    body{
        background: green;
    }
}
```

Opening this project on my nexus 5 the background is red and not yellow, why? What I'm missing?
I've uploaded it here http://untruste.altervista.org/Try.html

Comment: from 992 to 1199, its yellow..

Comment: tested in ff and chrome..working fine then what's the issue?

Comment: Have you got a meta tag like this? `<meta content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">`

Comment: @JamieBarker I've added this viewport and now the background is black! http://untruste.altervista.org/Try.html  (this is where I've uploaded it)

Comment: @untruste, even i just checked your link and it is working. i can see yellow background color from 992 to 1191 and from 1192 to 1199 its black..

Comment: but in your example, its ok then what is the issue?

Comment: You've moved the default background to be after the media queries so it will always be black currently

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/1MCWRfy.png

Comment: You also need to remove the max width as that does nothing.

Comment: @Leothelion why Do I have to get negative marks? If I wrote on this website it's because I don't know how to do something.

Comment: @untruste, then please read more..come with the problem which is real problem not with any code lines and wasting time of people..you even don't know how to use queries but showing like..SO is not learning center..keep in mind..

Comment: @Leothelion if you don't have patience to  help beginner programmers then u aren't on the right website. If you think you are wasting time here then why you have to answer to me? You think this question it's 'idiot'? Well, go over, don't answer, you don't have to put your comment in every question. Let people who really enjoy programming helps people who are trying to resolve their noob problems.And by the way, I said in the answer that the problem was with my nexus 5 and your comment shows that you didn't read the question "Damn..now i noticed..you are opening site in mobile "

Comment: @untruste, there is no need to over react..go and check my profile and you will find that even asking in damn good question,i got too many negative marks and i complained but what i learnd that SO is not learning center..people will help you if you are in right direction. M not being rude but THIS IS THE CULTURE OF SO. and we MUST have to comment so people won't waste their time as we did.. Off course we all tried to help you but really in this question..totally useless and won't help other user as well.

Comment: and off course i read the question, created fiddle, was checking in ff and chrome but look even after trying a lot what i have to listen.. again m saying SO is not a magic box where you will come and ask anything and it will give to you..but you MUST put a valid input then it will give  you right output..again m saying m not RUDE but its the  CULTURE OF SO. Go and check my previous question and you will see why m like this..SO made me like this and it will always be like this..So better msging me, read and prepare yourself how to ask question in good way..that will help better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its because 1920x1080 px is not real resolution of your device but rendered resolution, real resolution for mobile devices is around 360x480, thats why your screen become black after adding meta with viewport. Its possible that your browser showed your page in resolution between 768 and 992px. There is a lot of things that can be said about and here is article about it:

http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html

so you can target resolution, which mobile device provides by default(which is not my favorite option) or you can add meta tag with viewport(therfore force them to show pages to show in real resolution and dont render pixels) and target real resolutions of devices, so with your current query mobiles will have black background, tablets red or larger ones in landscape mode will have yellow and most of desktops will have green  background

Comment: Ok, u took me on the right way. So let me know if I've understand. I have to use the viewport <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no,initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
and then use css pixel instead of rendered pixel, where I can get some standard size?

Comment: not have to, but can do that, its simplier and more precise, but there are more ways you can do what you need

Answer (score -1):

Please add max width with media queries like

```
/*Small devices (tablets, 768px and up)*/  

@media (min-width: 768px)and
(max-width:991px) {
body {
background: red;
}
}

/*Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width:1191px) {
body{
background: yellow;
}
}

/*Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    body{
    background: green;
}
}
```

Comment: no need for max width this time, there is only one property and its overwriting correctly

Comment: @bhupendra then what about 1192 to 1199?